# Why I get permission denied output why I run, pkexec /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run ? Is it normal?

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, gksu, pkexec

I was following a [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890818/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-start-xampp-control-panel) to add Xampp server in "Show all application" section where normally we can see all GUI apps installed.

But it's different in case of Xampp. We have to do things manually. 
So I opened the file using:

```
pkexec nano /usr/share/applications/xampp-control-panel.desktop
```

Because I can't use this:

```
007@bond:~$ pkexec gedit /usr/share/applications/xampp-control-panel.desktop

Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(org.gnome.gedit:17349): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:18:25.529: cannot open display:
```

Anyhow when I tried putting to check whether Xampp run pkexec, I got this error:

```
007@bond:~$ Exec=pkexec /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
bash: /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run: Permission denied
```

**My questions/doubt**:

1. Isn't **pkexec** is a replacement of **gksudo**? Then why don't it works sometimes?

Comment: Why did you use `Exec=pkexec` there but not in the other commands?

Comment: @muru u didn't read the link i mentioned in the question, did u? See the "accepted answer". In "usr/share/applications/xampp-control-panel.desktop" we need to add exec = gksudo < > . Since gksudo has been removed with pkexec. So, i tried using it.

Comment: Nowhere in the link do they tell you to run `Exec=pkexec` in a terminal.

Comment: @muru no. Both question and answer is when gksudo existed. 
pkexec doesn't work when i also use it without exec. Exec is just a small way to run something.

Comment: No, it's not. It's a line from a .desktop file. The command run on the terminal shouldn't have the `Exec=`, like in your earlier two attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pkexec` command is used **in a GUI** to open a file that only root normally can write to. For instance, if you want to use `gedit` to open the file, you should use `pkexec` on it.

However, your paste of the error you had trying to open it with `pkexec` shows that you're most probably not in a GUI, since the `$DISPLAY` variable is empty (according to that message):

```
Gtk-WARNING **: 20:18:25.529: cannot open display:
```

It's possible that you're in a GUI, but that somehow you lost the `$DISPLAY` setting. For example, if you're ssh'd into another machine, you need to use ssh's X11 forwarding options (`-X` or perhaps `-Y`) to forward the GUI display so clients on that machine can display on yours.

If you don't mind using a terminal text mode editor, such as `nano`, then simply use `sudo` directly:

```
$ sudo nano /usr/share/applications/xampp-control-panel.desktop
```

Or, even better, use `sudoedit` (or equivalent `sudo -e`) with the path of the file you want to edit, if you have configured your editor correctly, in which case `sudo` will create a copy of the file that you can edit, then open your editor as your unprivileged user and finally copy the modified contents back to the original location, overwriting the file you wanted to modify.

Comment: @fibranden I know that sudo nano know. Problem is why pkexec becomes useless for me. Yes, I am a GUI laptop (Ubuntu 19.04) user. How can I solve this "display" warning that shows up in the terminal?

Comment: If you type `echo "$DISPLAY"`, does it show you something, or just an empty line? If an empty line, then there's your problem...

Comment: It shows me this: ":0" A colon and a zero. What this means?

Comment: That looks correct. I assume you'll be able to use `gedit` by itself to open the file (only you won't be able to save it.) There seems to be something wrong when you call `pkexec` then... But it's hard to tell from that message alone, it really looks as the `$DISPLAY` is being lost, but hard to tell where... Keep digging see if you find anything.

Comment: @fibranden thanks. Should I change the title of the question to the original problem? The "Gtk-WARNING **: 20:18:25.529: cannot open display". On ur mark.

Comment: Yes, possibly you'd get more relevant information from that, if that's the problem you want to debug... Or ask a separate question maybe, that doesn't involve editing files, but troubleshooting pkexec instead... Make sure you include enough information about your setup: OS version, GUI that you're using, X11 vs Wayland, which terminal you're typing the pkexec command on, the fact that `echo "$DISPLAY"` works, etc. That might help you get more useful answers to help you debug pkexec.

Comment: I think I'd recommend you ask a new question about "pkexec doesn't work" or similar. Having a question with no answers posted will also help you attract more attention to it. I'd go that route if I was in your place.

Comment: I would prefer `sudoedit` instead of `sudo nano`

Comment: @Kulfy Agreed, see my last paragraph on `sudo -e` which is the same as `sudoedit` (I believe `sudo -e` was introduced first and the `sudoedit` command later, but I may possibly be misremembering that...) Cheers!

Comment: @filbranden Missed that. I was carried away by `sudo nano` :P

Comment: @Kulfy thanks. I never knew there was such things as sudo -e or sudoedit. Both seem to work but shows the files differents. sudoedit = nano and sudo edit = vim.

Comment: `sudo edit` != `sudo -e`, the former is calling an `edit` command you might have. `sudoedit` and `sudo -e` *should* be identical and behave exactly the same, as far as I can tell...

Comment: @Prabeshbhattarai `edit` invokes [`run-mailcap`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/run-mailcap.1.html). `/usr/bin/edit` is a symlink to `run-mailcap`.

Comment: @Kulfy but it says, "GNU nano 3.2" at the top whenever i edit anything with "sudoedit a.txt". Does that means its "nano text editor"?

Comment: @Prabeshbhattarai Not necessarily. `sudoedit` invoke `editor` variable. In my system `nano` is selected by default. If you want to know about the priorities and current settings, run `sudo update-alternatives --display editor` and to change default editor run `sudo update-alternatives --config editor`. Moreover I think the comments are getting deviated from the actual question. If you have further queries on sudoedit, please ask a new questions. Thanks :)

Comment: @Kulfy got it. Thanks ciao